# Flowable - Change deployment key

Tags: flowable

I would like to change my deployment key but it's not working. Following docs, this is what has to be done:

```
repositoryService.setDeploymentKey(deploymentId, key);
```

but the key doesn't change for my deployment. Also, neither the method for changing the category (that is analogous) is working. Any idea why?

**EDIT**

After deploying an xml file, I simply perform a GET request to get all deployments, then I try to change one of them. I copy the deploymentId and then call `setDeploymentKey` with the deploymentId and the new key I want to set. Then I check if it's changed by doing a new GET request to get all deployments and the deployment still has the old key. No trace of the new one.

Comment: There are tests that are testing exactly this method. The test is [`DeploymentCategoryTest`](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/blob/master/modules/flowable-engine/src/test/java/org/flowable/engine/test/api/repository/DeploymentCategoryTest.java). Can you perhaps provide a reproducal test or code that would show when this is not working?

Comment: @Filip modified question. I can't provide a reproducible example

Comment: the test I linked in my previous comment does exactly what you described in the modified question. Unfortunately without a reproducible example I can't be of more help. We don't need your actual process or code, we only need an example that demonstrates the problem